# How to set optimum value for storm.config.setMessageTimeoutSecs

Tags: apache, apache-storm

I am working on Apache storm topology. I have different bolts who carrying out functionality like cosmosdb insertion , REST api call etc.

I want to set value for storm.config.setMessageTimeoutSecs for my Storm topology.

Now I have set it for 5 min, still I can see failures at spot side due to message time out. Is there any max value for message time out for topology.

and How to set optimum value for storm.config.setMessageTimeoutSecs

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a maximum timeout, no. You probably don't want to set it too high though, since it will mean that if a tuple is actually lost during network transfer, it will take much longer to figure out that it's been lost and to replay it.

Are you setting topology.max.spout.pending to a reasonable value? That can help to avoid too many tuples in flight at a time, which helps keep the complete latency down.

I'd also look at whether 5+ minutes is a reasonable processing time for your tuples. I don't know your use case, so maybe that's reasonable, but it seems like a long time to me.

If you actually need to process some tuples that will take such a long time, you might consider splitting your topology into smaller topologies, so you can set a high timeout for the slow part, and a lower timeout for the rest.